# dropdown menu changing position of list elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

When I add a dropdown menu to my liquid navigation bar, all of the list elements are pushed down to the same level my dropdown menu ends.

How do I fix this ?

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgdjtezu/3/)

**HTML**

```
<nav id='menu'>     
        <ul>
            <li><a href=''>home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href=''>categories</a>
                <ul id='hidden-list'>
                    <li><a href=''>test 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>test 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>test 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>test 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href=''>donate</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>contact</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>about</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:arial;
}
#menu {
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li{
    margin-top:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    margin-left:2.5%;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:300%;
    color:gold;
}

#menu li a:hover{
    color:black;
}

#hidden-list {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width:200px;
}

#hidden-list li a {
    color:black;
    font-size:200%;
}

#hidden-list li a:hover {
    color:gold;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('html').animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 4000 });
            $('ul li:nth-child(2) a').mouseenter(function() {
                $('#hidden-list').css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
            $('#hidden-list').mouseleave(function() {
                $('#hidden-list').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `position: absolute;`? It will take an element "out of the flow" of the page, such that it won't affect other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Need to Change CSS : `position: absolute;` that property Define  positioning method used for an element (static, relative, absolute or fixed).